# Bootstrap: my columns aren't showing inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to make a css based on bootstrap writing only those elements that I know I'll use in my webpage but there's a problem: when I customize the columns in my style.css the elements aren't being displayed in a single line, there is a break between these, here's a picture:

[image]

```css
html
{
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
.container
{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row
{
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.logo, .bar, .post
{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.logo, .bar, .post
{
  float: left;
}
.logo{width: 30%;background-color: yellow;}
.bar{width: 40%;background-color: blue;}
.post{width: 30%;background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">hello</div>
    <div class="bar">world</div>
    <div class="post">bruh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to use Bootstrap, use Bootstrap. Your CSS doesn't factor in the padding values you've added, which the `col-` classes do.

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using the Bootstrap grid system for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the default Bootstrap columns (such as in @Booster's answer)?

---

However, if you want to make inline columns by yourself:

The problem is that you're adding `padding` to each `<div>`, which is causing additional width.

To make the `padding` part of the entire width, add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the

```
.logo, .bar, .post
```

styles.

See working example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u50n4dd2/).

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use the default bootstrap cols?

```
<div class="col-md-4">Hello</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Word</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Bruh</div>
```

[bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap you can use the prefix **col-** inside an element with **row** as a class

for example,

with md like **col-md** meaning for meduim size devices

with sm like **col-sm** for small devices

and  lg like **col-lg** for large devices

and you can only use 12 column 
example for meduim device

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1">col 1</div>
     ... 
   <div class="col-md-1">col 12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `box-sizing`:

```css
html
{
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
.container
{
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.row
{
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.logo, .bar, .post
{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo, .bar, .post
{
  float: left;
}
.logo{width: 30%;background-color: yellow;}
.bar{width: 40%;background-color: blue;}
.post{width: 30%;background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">hello</div>
    <div class="bar">world</div>
    <div class="post">bruh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jonathan, we've made it simultaneously :)
I upvoted your unswer now.